# Is $f$ is closed equivalent to the graph of $f$ is closed when $f$ is linear

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $X,Y$ are topological vector spaces, $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a linear map, is that true that two of the following are equivalnet:

1.$f$ is closed

2.The graph of $f$ is closed.

What if $X,Y$ are $F-$ space or Banach space?

Comment: If X,Y are Banach spaces then: $f$ continuous $\Leftrightarrow$ The graph of $f$ is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider any Banach space $X$ and its dense subspace $Y.$ Then the identity $I:Y\to X$ is continuous hence its graph is closed in $Y\times X$ but it is not closed since $I(Y)=Y$ is dense subset of $X.$

Comment: Does closed linear operator implied closed graph?

Comment: Yes, because if $x_n \to x_0 $ then $T(x_n )\to T(x_0 )$ hence if $(x_n ,T(x_n ))\to (x_0 ,y_0 ) $ then it must be $y_0 =T(x_0 )$ because any sequence has no more that one limit in metric spaces.